# Tables Design for multiple products require different user info to order

Tags: mysql, database

There are multiple financial products with slight difference, each requires basic personal information when ordering, some need different extend information, eg.

---

- UserInfo-Basic

  - id
  - name
- UserInfo-Ext1

  - email
  - phone
- UserInfo-Ext2

  - id-card
  - id-card photo
- UserInfo-Ext3

  - bank card no.

---

- Product-Category

  - name
- Product-Property

  - property
- Product

  - properties

---

- Now:

  - product 1 needs UserInfo-Basic
  - product 2 needs UserInfo-Basic, UserInfo-Ext1
  - product 3 needs UserInfo-Basic, UserInfo-Ext2
  - product 4 needs UserInfo-Basic, UserInfo-Ext1, UserInfo-Ext2, UserInfo-Ext3

How to link Product with UserInfo?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to have one `UserInfo` table, with all columns (with the last five being nullable), and one `Product` table (with column/columns that indicate required UserInfo items) and then implement the business rules (product 2 needs UserInfo-Basic, UserInfo-Ext1) via triggers.  How you have it conceptually mapped out in your question would be a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: Thanks, what do you mean **"triggers"**? On database level or doing by programming (hard) code?

Comment: Database triggers to ensure all necessary fields in UserInfo are present for a product type.

Answer (score 0):

Should be able to have one query of left join

pseudocode

```
select b.columns..., x1.columnss... x2.columnss. x3.columns...
from userinfo-basic b
left join userInfo-ext1 x1
left join UserInfo-ext2 x2
left join UserInfo-ext3 x3
```

regardless of the Product you should be able to pick what you want from the userinfo table